# Pass javascript variable as javascript function parameter from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a global javascript parameter declared at the top of my script: param2.

I am calling my function on body load.

I would like to pass my global javascript parameter to a javscript function.

```
<script language="javascript">
var param2;
...
function tableAppend(param1){
...
}
</script>

<body onload="tableAppend('param2');">
```

I am far from a professional with javascript, but I don't think there is a way to "concatenate" in HTML.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  I have seen answers on here about passing variables to a function, but not passing a javascript variable

Comment: As the variable is global, you don't even have to pass it. `tableAppend` is direct access to `param2`.

Comment: @Felix Kling Good eye :) Thank you very much my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me, if anyone else is wondering about the answer, you simply need to remove the single quotes from the parameter name!